# bootstrap html css toggle more info div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

If I have a `<div class="parent"></div>` I want to make this type of card so that at the base of the card I need to add a `plus` button. When the plus button is clicked, that will toggle another div to show, the button will change to `minus`. When minus button is clicked that will toggle the additional div to hide returning to initial stage. I am using bootstrap and need to create those cards within a row. All elements must be within same `parent` div.

Something like this: Please notice these 3 images show the event life cycle of a single card.

My question is: how can I have the button at the center of the bottom border, and keep the border there at the same time when the box is expanded?

My attempt: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1p8vrox/1/)

[image]

Comment: @ZimSystem: Please check the jsFiddle link.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the question/problem? Is it the issue with toggling the other cards, or changing the +/- icon?

Comment: @ZimSystem: like you see from the picture the icon must stay on the center of the bottom border even when you toggle the more info section. In my attempt the border moves down instead of staying at the same place.

Comment: ok, so can you edit and clarify that the question is about position of the button? Currently the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your attempt is working. it just does not look right. you need a clearfix on the div that is showing when you click the button because you are using pull-left and pull-right which use float left and float right. here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/njzskdqr/

to read more about clearfix:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

just add the class cf to the parent with class collapse

```
.cf::before, .cf::after{
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.cf::after{
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: How can I keep the bottom border in place? Currently when clicking the button the bottom border expands with the more info box. The bottom border should stay in place and the more info box should appear at the bottom giving the impression that are 2 boxes instead of one. Like in the image I posted above, step 2, there is the border separating the main info box and the more info box.

Comment: u need to give it a set height

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute` for the icon button..

```
.btn.btn-info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 14px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/6TS1fcsXi6